# asp.net mvc EF navigation property same name in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have these two models

```
    public class Group
    { 
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }   
    public virtual Group Groups { get; set; }
}
```

using code first approach it creates Groups_GroupID as the foreign key in the user table when it generates the database. Specifying GroupID with displayname didn't work either because it is creating the same name.so how would i make it generate GroupID in the User Table? i am using EF 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ForeignKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) attribute on the navigational property

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]  
    public virtual Group Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Groups { get; set; }
}
```

But you might want to do this to handle the case where you might want many users to belong to a group and/or a user to belong to many groups.

```
public class Group
    { 
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```